# Angular Material themes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use a prebuilt theme by doing this in style.css:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';
```

But when I do this, the buttons just all appear with white backgrounds.

```
<button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
<button mat-button color="accent">Accent</button>
<button mat-button color="warn">Warn</button>
```

I thought putting the import statement in style.css would make the styling global and available to all files in the project. Am I incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share an example via StackBlitz? I took a material-starter project and setup the purple-greeen theme there: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-ykm3yo?file=main.ts

Could you double-check that you have the MatButton module imported? Try removing this import in the linked StackBlitz to maybe see the effect you're describing.

Comment: Hmm... I think one of the confusions is that I'm using Angular Material and Bootstrap in the same project. How can I get bootstrap colors to override the material ones?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by overriding the material colors with bootstrap ones? Could you edit the provided StackBlitz so that it matches your setup? It's easier to provide assistance then.

Comment: Anything you may want to add here?